# Python chr() command will not return Unicode values when given list of in-range integers

Tags: python, list, chr

This piece of code should take a list of integers and replace each integer with a Unicode value (chr() in this case operates with Unicode not ASCII in my version of python), instead it returns the same integers unchanged. Any ideas?

```
        x = 0
        while x != len(message):
            encrypt[x] = chr(encrypt[x])
            x=x+1
```

The list is as follows:

```
    encrypt = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Comment: You never touch or use `message` (apart from it's length), probably that's not what you want

Comment: I'm guessing that if @Chris_Rands is right, `len(message)` is 0.

Comment: Yeah, thats it. Thanks guys, guess I just needed a second pair of eyes on that one. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write :

```
encrypt = [chr(encrypt[i]) for i in range(len(message))]
```

but it's not an answer. Can you give us the original encrypt list ?